# How can I get one dimension from a bi-dimensional array in VB.Net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dimension

I have an application in VBA that gives to my VB.Net dll one bi-dimensional variant. It is a an array, in which every component is a another array containing two positions.

I want to get this two-position array. When I am using VBA I can access directly the data from each position by doing:

```
dataArray(index, 0) or dataArray(index, 1)
```

And when I want to get the two-position array I can use:

```
Dim posArray as variant
posArray = dataArray(index)
```

posArray(0) contains dataArray(index, 0) and posArray(1) contains dataArray(index, 1).

But when I am using VB.Net, I can access directly the data, just like the first example. However, when I try to get one dimension from the two-dimension array, like I did in the second example, it is not possible.

```
Dim posArray as Object
posArray = dataArray(index)
```

It says "Attempted to operate on an array with the incorrect number of dimensions."

I have tried everything to make it work, and I don't want to make the attribution one by one, like:

```
posArray(0) = dataArray(index, 0)
posArray(1) = dataArray(index, 1)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Am I missing something here? It seems like if you have a 1-D array of 1-D arrays your VBA syntax to access an "inner" element would be dataArray(index)(0), not dataArray(index, 0). It's been a while since I used anything.NET, and I know of no operator to get a 1-D array slice of a 2-D array. However, there's not one built into VBA either. (In Excel you can use the INDEX function from directly from VBA though.) So Jason Kester's answer is correct as far as slicing a 2-D array goes, but I'm still not sure if that was really your question.

Comment: I found a way to slice out 1 dimension from a multidimensional array, using VB.NET. Please see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to spin through and generate the 1D array yourself.  There's no library call in .NET to do it for you.

```
dim arraySlice as string[yourArrayWidth]
for index = 0 to yourArrayWidth
  arraySlice[index] = yourArray[4, index]
next
```

The example above would grab row 4 out of yourArray and stick it into arraySlice for you.  Naturally, you'll want to clean that up and put it into a function that accepts a rowIndex as a parameter (and another function for splitting vertically that accepts a columnIndex).

It's little functions like this that you'll collect over the years into your own utility library.  5 years from now, you'll need an ArraySlice and you'll already have a function to do it.

Comment: You can make a single call to copy one dimension of an array to a 1-D array, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Dim1Len As Integer = 5
Dim Dim2Len As Integer = 2
Dim DimToExtract As Integer = 2
Dim inMultiDArr(5, 2) As Integer
inMultiDArr = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
Dim outSingleDArr(5) As Integer
outSingleDArr = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Buffer.BlockCopy(inMultiDArr, Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Integer)) * Dim1Len * (DimToExtract - 1),
                 outSingleDArr, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Integer)) * Dim1Len)
```

After `BlockCopy` the 'outSingleDArr' will contain { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }. The above was derived from [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d525b76-f5b6-4340-a899-c3c82570d2e1/is-there-a-twodimensional-arraycopy-method-).